# Java - Escape star in character class in regex

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match a line with a regular expression. The line contains two numbers which could be divided by plus, minus or a star (multiplication). However, I am not sure how to escape the star.

```
line.matches("[0-9]*[+-*][0-9]*");
```

I tried also `line.matches("[0-9]*[+-\\*][0-9]*");` but it does not work either.

Should I put the star into separate group? Why does the escaping `\\*` not work in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`*` is not metacharacter in [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[...]`) so you don't need to escape it at all. What you need to escape is `-` because inside character class it is responsible for creating *range* of characters like `[a-z]`.

So instead of `"[+-*]"` which represents all characters placed in Unicode Table between `+` and `*` use

- `"[+\\-*]"`
- or place `-` where it can't be used as range indicator

  - at start of character class `[-+*]`
  - at end of character class `[+*-]`
  - or right after other range if you have one `[a-z-+*]`

BTW if you would like to add `\` literal to your operators you need to write it in regex as `\\` (it is metacharacter used for escaping or to access standard character classes like `\w` so we also need to escape it). But since `\` is also special in String literals (it can be used to represent characters via `\n` `\r` `\t` or `\uXXXX`), you also need to escape it there as well. So in regex `\` needs to be represented as `\\` which as string literal is written as `"\\\\"`.

BTW 2: to represent digit instead of `[0-9]` you can use `\d` (written in string literal as `"\\d"` since `\` is special there and requires escaping).

BTW 3: if you want to make sure that there will be at least two numbers in string (one on each side of operator) you need to use `+` instead of `*` at `[0-9]*` since `+` represents ***one*** or more occurrence of previous element, while `*` represents ***zero*** or more occurrences.

So your code can look like

```
line.matches("\\d+[-+*]\\d+");
```